# How to dynamically drop columns using column headers in pyspark dataframe?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

So I have a very wide and messy Pyspark dataframe that looks like this:

```
Abc    Def    Ghi    Jkl    Jkl1    Jkl_    Abc_    Abc1_
 0      0      1      0     null      1       1       2
```

The values are irrelevant but are useful to see this work. This goes on for thousands of fields.  It appears that this is the result of joining tables and adding either a '1' or '_' or both to the end of a column name to avoid duplication.  I can't fix that part, but need to drop all the 'original' tables and rename the remaining.

How can I compare all the column names against eachother like a fuzzy match etc, then drop the column without the 1 or _ (or both) and then rename the ones with 1 or _ (or both) to strip the 1 or _ (or both)

The end result would look like this:

```
Abc    Def    Ghi    Jkl      
 2      0      1      1
```

I can loop through the df and get the column names etc but I'm not sure how to do the fuzzy comparison.  I think if I had that, I could strip the undesired ending characters fine to get the end result.

Comment: If you know that "undesired ending characters" are always not letters you can try to remove all except letters from all columns and then compare 

`import re
print(re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]+', '', "Jkl1"))
#Jkl`

Comment: Fuzzy matching is far harder than understanding a pattern, if there is one. With the former, you would still need to define thresholds at which you decide that two strings are close enough (e.g. a Levenshtein distance of 1 might be acceptable?). I recommend you find the pattern, take `df.columns`, create a set of their “stems” and select only those columns.

Comment: what if the column names are `Xyz_1`, `Xyz1_`, which one should be kept, same to `X1` and `X_`